# Forward functors with minimal copying

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, c++14, perfect-forwarding

I'd like to forward functor call and copy that functor only when absolutely necessary. Here is my generic wrapper function and functor:

```
template <typename F>
void wrapper (F func)
{
  func ();
}

struct Functor
{
  Functor() {}
  void operator() () { /* do some work */ }
};
```

I can call wrapper with

1. *rvalue reference*: wrapper( Functor() );
2. *lvalue reference*: Functor f; wrapper(f);
3. *const lvalue reference*: const Functor f; wrapper(f);
4. *const rvalue reference*: const Functor make_functor (); wrapper (make_functor ());

I want to copy wrapper's arg only when const references was passed. So I come to such wrapper implementation:

```
using safe_mutual_handler_type =
  typename std::conditional<
    std::is_reference<F>::value
  , typename std::conditional<
      std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<F>::type>::value
    , typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<F>::type>::type
    , F&
    >::type
  , F&
  >::type;

template <typename F>
void wrapper (F&& func)
{
  safe_mutual_handler_type<F> tmp = func;
  tmp ();
}
```

Not very nice and misses (not very typical) const-rvalue-reference case, but basically do its work.

But I may also have Functor with const operator()

```
struct Functor {
  Functor() {}
  void operator() () const {}
};
```

And in that case I do not need to copy wrapper's arg at all.

The question is: how may I check in wrapper if **Functor** has const parenthesis operator? The other question is if the **wrapper** may be implemented in more smart and compact way without huge number of lines of type traits typedefs? (actually I'm worrying not about code size but about code readability).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to use references if the call with them is valid, use expression SFINAE:

```
template <typename F>
auto wrapper_ (F&& func, int) -> decltype(func())
{
    func ();
}

template <typename F>
void wrapper_ (F func, ...)
{
    func ();
}

template <typename F>
void wrapper (F&& f)
{
    wrapper_(std::forward<F>(f), 0);
}
```

If you only want to copy/move it when you pass a mutable reference (and only then):

```
template <typename F>
auto wrapper_ (F&& func, std::true_type)
{
    func ();
}

template <typename F>
void wrapper_ (F func, std::false_type.)
{
    func ();
}

template <typename F>
void wrapper (F&& f)
{
    wrapper_(std::forward<F>(f), std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<F>::type>());
}
```